# In the playwright context.pages not work correctly

Tags: python, windows, playwright

In the playwright package in the jupyter notebook environment, the context.pages command returns all windows that are open, but it does not work correctly when running the codes in file.py.

I use code in windows 10 and python 3.120

context.pages return 1 page in main.py

Comment: What do you mean by "[does not work](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) correctly" exactly? Can you share a runnable [mcve] of the code that produces the problem? What version of Playwright are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.